# Select twice for check any check-box in one2many field odoo10

Tags: checkbox, odoo, odoo-10, one2many

I Have added check-box in one2many field. But for marking check this check-box, it takes twice click on this check-box. So, how to active this check-box in single click?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any kind of error is raised while you clicked that on single time ? Error from JS in browser console ?

Comment: No, But someone suggest me for one2many field it takes 2 action on first click it activate the one2many field and in another click it checked. but i want it on only one click.

Comment: I don't find this type of thing in odoo10 o2m field. I also checked the same in runbot also but not happening here.

Comment: But, i am facing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

**For Odoo CE v12:**
In the tree view, placing `class="custom-control custom-checkbox"` next to the `One2many` field enables checking the box in a single click.

**Example:**

```
<field name="your-One2many-field" class="custom-control custom-checkbox"> </field>
```

Comment: Which works up to v15 (including). For v16 couldn't find a solution yet

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you mean. To confirm, this issue is for any `One2many` field, which is displayed as a tree view within a form view, correct?

If that is the case, then this is, unfortunately, normal behavior. You must click the line once to place it in "edit" mode and then check or uncheck the checkbox.

I'm not aware of any existing way to override this behavior currently. I expect that changing this would require modifying at least the JavaScript code.

With that being said, you could place a `<button>` element somewhere on your `One2many` field's tree view that would toggle your checkbox field, but that's not entirely desirable.

Comment: Yes, This issue occurs in one2many field. And still i'm not able to get any solution regarding this issue. Did you found any solution?

Comment: @PAWANSHARMA I have not found any solution except for using a `button` on your `One2many` field's tree view. Such as `<button name="action_toggle_checkbox" type="object" .../>` which calls a method that just does something like `for record in self: record.field = not record.field`